# How to make maven workaround with sun.misc.unsafe

Tags: java, maven

I used sun.misc.unsafe inside maven. However, when building the project the error shows:

> [ERROR] UnsafeUtil.java:[43,2] Unsafe is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

So how could I configure maven to build the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Maven Compiler plugin parameter [compilerArgs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs) to pass the -XDignore.symbol.file option to java compiler.